# Problems with parsing excel file with vba

Tags: regex, parsing, vba, excel

I am VBA newbie and have the following problem.

I am given an excel file with house numbers where each house has corresponding flat numbers. The tricky thing here is that there is no structured way of displaying this data.

By this I mean that for ex. I have the house number N10 in the cell **(4:ABC)** and under this cell I have random number of flat numbers. The same thing for the house number 11 that is located in cell **(4:DEF)** with again random number of flats under it.  I need to bring this data into structured way where the number of flat would be located in one column with the corresponding house number in the next column.. Another problem is that in one document there are around 15 sheets with similar data and there are around 20 such excel documents. So, it's a lot of data that need to be consolidated into 1 structured document.

I have no idea how to start. It's quite hard to parse this data, although I assume I have to use regular expressions. What helps is that the house number consists of 2 digits, whereas flat numbers are almost all of the same format - (5 digits and a letter). so I assume I can go through each cell and those that match regexp write into the new document but then there will be a problem of matching with the house number? Please, anyone? any thoughts...

My Input:

```
   |  A   |  B   |  C   |  D   |  E   |  F   |       | ...   | N    |
  1|             Header                      |       | ...   |      |
  2|             Header  N2                  |       | ...   |      |
  3|             Header N3                   |       | ...   |      |
  4|         N9/10      |      |      N11/12         | ...
  5|Smith               |      |Jones |Tim   |       | ...
  6|Green               |      |Singh |Roth  |       | ...
  7|Abbott              |      |Patel |              | ...
  8|11111a|22222a|33333a|      |22222a|33333a| 44444c|
  9|11111b|22222b|33333b|      |22222b|33333b| 44443d|
   :
 21|11111u|22222u|33333u|      |22222u|33333u| 44444e|
 22|      |22222v|33333v|      |22222v|33333v| 77777e|
 23|      |      |33333w|      |      |      |       | 
 24|      |      |33333x|      |      |      |       |
   :
                B L A N K          CELLS
   .                                            .
   .                                            .
 31|       N375/376     |      |  N96/85     |
 32|Smith               |      |Jones |Tim   |       | ...
 33|Green               |      |Singh |Roth  |       | ...
 34|Abbott              |      |Patel |              | ...
 35|11111a|22222a|33333a|      |22222a|33333a| 44444c|
 36|11111b|22222b|33333b|      |22222b|33333b| 44443d|
   :
 45|11111u|22222u|33333u|      |22222u|33333u| 44444e|
 46|      |22222v|33333v|      |22222v|33333v| 77777e|
 47|      |      |33333w|      |      |33333w|
```

Answers to your questions:

1. In rows 1 to 3 only headers of the document, the name of the city, the region (not     important at all )
2. Surnames don't match the number of flats and I don't know why. This information is not important for me
3. rows 25-30 - blank, 45-50 blank, 61-64 - blank, 69-78 - blank and in some cases 88 - 106 is blank too in some cases the document ends on 87
4. Rows are different, that's the problem. For example, you can see that under the house 11/12 there rows are of the similar length but that's just a coincidence. there is no a certain length of rows under each house
5. yes, there are blank cells as explained in 3.
6. I noticed that in all documents the last column used is N
7. I ignore the surnames because I don't need them

What I want:

```
 |  A   |  B   |  C   | 
1|11111a|N9/10 |      | 
2|11111b|N9/10 |      |
3|11111c|N9/10 |      | 
 : 
x|11111a|N11/12|      |
x|11111b|N11/12|      |
x|11111c|N11/12|      |
```

Comment: "I have no idea how to start." Start by *showing* us (not telling us about) an example of your input and of your desired output. Used `fixed width font` to represent your spreadsheet.

Comment: currently it's 23:35 here but I may stay up until 3am if needed.

Comment: @Bill. Go to bed. I am about to stop for dinner. I will have something ready for when you get up.  I am deleting obsolete comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to get you started.  I have found it difficult to test my code but I hope there are not too many mistakes.  I have included comments explaining the purpose of each section but I do not know if you know enough VBA to understand how I am achieving the purpose.

I need you to move (or copy) all the workbooks from which data is to be extracted (the source workbooks) to the same folder.  My first macro will work better if that folder only contains the source workbooks and the workbook I will ask you to create.

Within that folder, I need you to create a new workbook named something like "Consolidate.xls".  (I am using Excel 2003, you may have a different extension.)

Open Consolidate.xls then open the VB Editor.  (I am assuming a basic knowledge of Excel macros.  If necessary you will have to wait for me to get up.  You are about six hours ahead of me and I am retired so I do not get up a crack of dawn.)

Create a module and copy the code below to it.

Run the macro `FillSourceSheets`.  This create a worksheet "SourceSheets" and fills it with workbook and worksheet names.  On my system, it looked like:

```
 |   A  |       B             |     C     |  D   |   E  | 
 |Status|Source workbook      |Source worksheets -->    |       
 |      |Consolidate.txt      |Consolidate|      |      |
 |      |Test Parse data 1.xls|Sheet1     |Sheet2|Sheet3|
 |      |Test Parse data 2.xls|Sheet1     |Sheet4|Sheet2|Sheet3|
```

Do not worry about the Status column for now.

The names under "Source workbook" are the files that Excel can open.  Note that it can open a text file.  "Test Parse data 1.xls" and "Test Parse data 2.xls" are my test workbooks.  The worksheets within each file are listed in the sequence found.

You need to delete any rows for files that not source files.  I had to delete the row for "Consolidate.txt".  You need to delete the name of any worksheet that does not contain source data.  In my case "Sheet4" of "Test Parse data 2.xls" does not contain source data and I had to delete it.  They must not be any gaps.  A row with nothing in Column B ends the list.  A cell with nothing in it ends a row.  So after editing my sheet it looked like:

```
 |   A  |       B             |     C     |  D   |   E  | 
 |Status|Source workbook      |Source worksheets -->    |       
 |      |Test Parse data 1.xls|Sheet1     |Sheet2|Sheet3|
 |      |Test Parse data 2.xls|Sheet1     |Sheet2|Sheet3|
```

This list is what drives the other macros.  It tells them which workbooks and sheets to look at.

The other macro I have included is `ValidateSheets`

You have 20 workbooks of which one contains 15 worksheets.  It will be amazing if none contains errors and it will be amazing if some do not conform to the format you have given me.  `ValidateSheets` does a first level validate because there is no purpose doing more until we know precisely what we have.

`ValidateSheets` works down the list of workbooks and worksheets in "SourceSheets".  It creates a text file "Process Report.txt" listing its progress.  If it finds an error in "SourceSheets", it stop immediately with a message on the screen.  There should not being any errors in "SourceSheets" but if there are you will have to fix them an restart the macro.  If it finds an error in a worksheet, it output an error message to "Process Report.txt" and continues with the next worksheet.

Try running `ValidateSheets` and see what progress you make.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FillSourceSheets()

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ErrMsg As String
  Dim Filename As String
  Dim InxWSheet As Long
  Dim PathCrnt As String
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim WBookOther As Workbook
  Dim WBookThis As Workbook

  If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
    ' It is easy to get into a muddle if there are multiple workbooks
    ' open at the start of a macro like this.  Avoid the problem.
    Call MsgBox("Please close all other workbooks", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' Record this workbook so we do not confuse it with any we open
  Set WBookThis = ActiveWorkbook
  ' Record the folder containing the current workbook
  PathCrnt = ActiveWorkbook.Path

  ' Create a new worksheet, name it SourceSheets and fill the heading row
  Sheets.Add
  With ActiveSheet
    .Name = "SourceSheets"
    .Range("A1").Value = "Status"
    .Range("B1").Value = "Source workbook"
    .Range("C1").Value = "Source worksheets -->"
    .Range("C1:E1").MergeCells = True
    .Range("A1:C1").Font.Bold = True
  End With
  RowCrnt = 2

  Filename = Dir$(PathCrnt & "\*.*")
  ' Loop for every file in the activeworkbook's folder
  Do While Filename <> ""
    If Filename <> ActiveWorkbook.Name Then
      ' This file is not the active workbook
      ' so try to open it as a workbook.
      Err.Clear
      ErrMsg = ""
      On Error Resume Next
      Set WBookOther = Workbooks.Open(PathCrnt & "\" & Filename)
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ' On Error GoTo 0 clears Err.Num and Err.Description so save
        ErrMsg = Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
      End If
      On Error GoTo 0
      If ErrMsg <> "" Then
        ' This file cannot be opened by Excel
        Debug.Print Filename & " " & ErrMsg
      Else
        ' This file has been successfully opened.  Create a row for it.
        ' Start by placing the file name in column 2.
        WBookThis.Sheets("SourceSheets").Cells(RowCrnt, 2).Value = Filename
        ColCrnt = 3
        ' Place each sheet name in a cell starting from column 3
        For InxWSheet = 1 To WBookOther.Worksheets.Count
          WBookThis.Sheets("SourceSheets").Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value = _
                                    WBookOther.Worksheets(InxWSheet).Name
          ColCrnt = ColCrnt + 1
        Next
        WBookOther.Close SaveChanges:=False
        RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1
      End If
    End If
    Filename = Dir$       ' Get next file name
  Loop
  With WBookThis.Sheets("SourceSheets")
    .Columns.AutoFit
  End With

End Sub
Sub ValidateSheets()

  Dim CellValue As String
  Dim ColSrcList As Long
  Dim ColSrcSheetCrnt As Long
  Dim ColSrcSheetLast As Long
  Dim Found As Boolean
  Dim InxWSheetCrnt As Long
  Dim OutputFileNum As Integer
  Dim PathCrnt As String
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowSrcList As Long
  Dim RowSrcSheetBlockStart As Long
  Dim RowSrcSheetCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcSheetFinal As Long
  Dim WBookOtherNameCrnt As String
  Dim WSheetOtherNameCrnt As String
  Dim WBookOther As Workbook
  Dim WBookThis As Workbook

  If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
    ' It is easy to get into a muddle if there are multiple workbooks
    ' open at the start of a macro like this.  Avoid the problem.
    Call MsgBox("Please close all other workbooks", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' Record this workbook so we do not confuse it with any we open
  Set WBookThis = ActiveWorkbook
  ' Record the folder containing the current workbook
  PathCrnt = ActiveWorkbook.Path
  ' Open text file to which progress messages will be written
  OutputFileNum = FreeFile
  Open PathCrnt & "\Process Report.txt" For Output Lock Write As #OutputFileNum

  With WBookThis.Sheets("SourceSheets")
    ' Load name of first workbook and first worksheet
    RowSrcList = 2      ' Row of first workbook
    ColSrcList = 3      ' Column of first worksheet
    WBookOtherNameCrnt = .Cells(RowSrcList, 2).Value
    WSheetOtherNameCrnt = .Cells(RowSrcList, ColSrcList).Value
  End With

  ' This loop repeats for each worksheet listed in worksheet SourceSheets
  Do While True
    ' WBookOtherNameCrnt and WSheetOtherNameCrnt have been loaded either
    ' before this loop or by the code at the end
    If Not WBookOther Is Nothing Then
      ' There is an open workbook.  Check it is the one
      ' required for this loop.
      If LCase(WBookOtherNameCrnt) <> LCase(WBookOther.Name) Then
        ' This is not the same workbook.
        ' Close the open workbook and clear reference to it
        WBookOther.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Set WBookOther = Nothing
      End If
    End If
    If WBookOther Is Nothing Then
      ' The workbook to be tested is not open so we need to
      ' open it.  First check it exists
      If Dir$(PathCrnt & "\" & WBookOtherNameCrnt) <> "" Then
        ' The specified file exists but it may not be a valid workbook.
        ' Use Excel's error handling
        Err.Clear
        On Error Resume Next
        Set WBookOther = Workbooks.Open(PathCrnt & "\" & WBookOtherNameCrnt)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
          Call MsgBox("Open of """ & WBookOtherNameCrnt & """ failed. " & _
                  "Error: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly)
          Set WBookOther = Nothing
          Close OutputFileNum       ' Close text file
          Exit Sub
        End If
      Else
        Call MsgBox("I could not find workbook """ & WBookOtherNameCrnt _
                                     & """", vbOKOnly)
        Close OutputFileNum       ' Close text file
        Exit Sub
      End If
    End If
    ' The required workbook is open.
    With WBookOther

      ' Check the worksheet exists
      Found = False
      For InxWSheetCrnt = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
        If .Worksheets(InxWSheetCrnt).Name = WSheetOtherNameCrnt Then
          Found = True
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
      If Not Found Then
        ' The workbook was not found
        Call MsgBox("I could not find worksheet """ & WSheetOtherNameCrnt _
             & """ with workbook """ & WBookOtherNameCrnt & """", vbOKOnly)
        .Close
        Close OutputFileNum       ' Close text file
        Exit Sub
      End If

      Print #OutputFileNum, "Process sheet """ & WSheetOtherNameCrnt & _
            """ of workbook """ & WBookOther.Name & """"

      With Sheets(WSheetOtherNameCrnt)

        ' Validate source sheet matches expected format
        ' Rows 1 to 3 are ignored.

        ' Find final row of sheet
        Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), _
                                       xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If Rng Is Nothing Then
          ' The sheet is empty
          Print #OutputFileNum, "  Sheet is empty"
          Exit Do
        End If
        RowSrcSheetFinal = Rng.Row

        ' There are one of more blocks.  The first block starts in Row 4

        RowSrcSheetBlockStart = 4
        Do While True       ' Loop for each block
          ' Row 1 of a block must consider of one or more three cell merged
          ' areas.  Each merged area contains a string with value of format:
          ' "N" number "/" number.
          ' Search backwards from the column 1 of the next row
          ' for a cell with a value
          Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(RowSrcSheetBlockStart + 1, 1), _
                                            xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
          If Rng Is Nothing Then
            ' This should not be possible because have
            ' already check for empty sheet
            Print #OutputFileNum, "  Sheet is empty"
            Exit Do
          End If
          If Rng.Row <> RowSrcSheetBlockStart Then
            Print #OutputFileNum, "  I was expecting a value on row " & _
                                                           RowSrcSheetBlockStart
            Exit Do
          End If
          ColSrcSheetLast = Rng.Column
          For ColSrcSheetCrnt = 1 To ColSrcSheetLast Step 3
            ' Check the three cells are merged
            If .Range(.Cells(RowSrcSheetBlockStart, ColSrcSheetCrnt), _
                 .Cells(RowSrcSheetBlockStart, ColSrcSheetCrnt + 2)).MergeCells _
                                                               = True Then
              If Not .Cells(RowSrcSheetBlockStart, ColSrcSheetCrnt).Value Like "N*/*" Then
                ' Cell does not contain "N" number "/" number
                Print #OutputFileNum, "  Row " & RowSrcSheetBlockStart & _
                        " is the start of a block. I was expecting " & _
                        "columns " & ColNumToCode(ColSrcSheetCrnt) & " to " & _
                        ColNumToCode(ColSrcSheetCrnt + 2) & " to contain a value with " & _
                        "the format ""N"" number ""/"" number"
                Exit Do
              End If
            Else
              ' Three cells are not merged
              Print #OutputFileNum, "  Row " & RowSrcSheetBlockStart & _
                    " is the start of a block. I was expecting " & _
                    "columns " & ColNumToCode(ColSrcSheetCrnt) & " to " & _
                    ColNumToCode(ColSrcSheetCrnt + 2) & " to be merged"
              Exit Do
            End If
          Next
          ' Cells with Rows 2 to 4 of a block must contain
          ' surnames or be empty.
          ' Check they do not contain flat numbers
          For RowSrcSheetCrnt = RowSrcSheetBlockStart + 1 To _
                                RowSrcSheetBlockStart + 3
            For ColSrcSheetCrnt = 1 To ColSrcSheetLast + 2
              CellValue = .Cells(RowSrcSheetCrnt, ColSrcSheetCrnt).Value
              If CellValue = "" Or Not LCase(CellValue Like "#####[a-z]") Then
                ' Cell valid
              Else
                ' Cell contains a flat number.  Cannot be a surname.
                Print #OutputFileNum, "  Row " & RowSrcSheetCrnt & _
                      " should only contain surnames but column " & _
                      ColNumToCode(ColSrcSheetCrnt) & " contains a flat number"
                Exit Do
              End If
            Next
          Next
          ' Rows 5 of a block to the next blank row should contain
          ' nothing but flat numbers.
          RowSrcSheetCrnt = RowSrcSheetBlockStart + 5
          Do While True     ' Loop until find a blank row
            Found = False  ' Nothing found on this row
            For ColSrcSheetCrnt = 1 To ColSrcSheetLast + 2
              CellValue = .Cells(RowSrcSheetCrnt, ColSrcSheetCrnt).Value
              If CellValue <> "" Then
                Found = True  ' Value found on this row
                If LCase(CellValue Like "#####[a-z]") Then
                  ' Cell valid
                Else
                  ' Cell does not contain a flat number
                  Print #OutputFileNum, "  Row " & RowSrcSheetCrnt & _
                        " should only contain flat numbers but column " & _
                        ColNumToCode(ColSrcSheetCrnt) & " contains " & CellValue
                  Exit Do
                End If
              End If
            Next
            If Not Found Then
              ' This is a blank line
              Exit Do
            End If
            RowSrcSheetCrnt = RowSrcSheetCrnt + 1
          Loop
          ' This block is finished.
          Print #OutputFileNum, "  No error found in block starting " & _
                                "on row " & RowSrcSheetBlockStart
          ' Is there another block?
          If RowSrcSheetCrnt > RowSrcSheetFinal Then
            ' No more blocks
            Exit Do
          Else
            ' Find the next row with a value which should be the first
            ' row of the next block.
            Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(RowSrcSheetCrnt, 1), _
                                          xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlNext)
            If Rng Is Nothing Then
              ' This should not be possible since
              ' have already found a value on a later row
              Print #OutputFileNum, "  I expected another block under row " _
                          & RowSrcSheetCrnt & " but I could not find it."
              Exit Do
            End If
            RowSrcSheetBlockStart = Rng.Row
          End If
        Loop
      End With
    End With

    ' Load details of next worksheet
    With WBookThis.Sheets("SourceSheets")
      ColSrcList = ColSrcList + 1
      ' Load name of next worksheet
      WSheetOtherNameCrnt = .Cells(RowSrcList, ColSrcList).Value
      If WSheetOtherNameCrnt = "" Then
        ' There are no more worksheets on this row
        RowSrcList = RowSrcList + 1
        WBookOtherNameCrnt = .Cells(RowSrcList, 2).Value
        If WBookOtherNameCrnt = "" Then
          ' End of list reached.
          Exit Do
        End If
        ColSrcList = 3
        WSheetOtherNameCrnt = .Cells(RowSrcList, ColSrcList).Value
        If WSheetOtherNameCrnt = "" Then
          Call MsgBox("Row " & RowSrcList & " of SourceSheets has a " & _
                      "workbook name but no worksheet name.", vbOKOnly)
          Close OutputFileNum       ' Close text file
          Exit Sub
        End If
      End If
    End With
  Loop

  If Not WBookOther Is Nothing Then
    WBookOther.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set WBookOther = Nothing
  End If

  Close OutputFileNum       ' Close text file

End Sub
Function ColCodeToNum(ColStg As String) As Long

  Dim lcColStg                  As String

  lcColStg = LCase(ColStg)
  ColCodeToNum = IIf(Len(ColStg) > 1, (Asc(Left(ColStg, 1)) - 64) * 26, 0) + _
                 Asc(Right(ColStg, 1)) - 64

End Function
Function ColNumToCode(ColNum As Long) As String

  ColNumToCode = IIf(ColNum > 26, Chr(64 + ((ColNum - 1) \ 26)), "") & _
                 Chr(65 + ((ColNum - 1) Mod 26))

End Function
```

Comment: @Bill. How is it going?  Did `FillSourceSheets` fall over, fill sheet "SourceSheets" with workbooks and worksheet names or something else?  Did `ValidateSheets` fall over?  If it worked, "ProgressReport.txt" should have a line for each worksheet together with an error report or one of more lines saying "No error found in block ...".  Error reports either indicate an error in my macro or that the sheets do not match your specification.  We need to identify the cause of every error report.

Comment: @Bill.  I have restudied your layout.  I had thought it was unchanged from my original but I have now noticed that columns D, H and so on are blank.  My macro does not allow for these blank columns.  If you can confirm this change, I will amend my macro to match.

Comment: Thank you, Tony. I run the code you have given. It actually found errors and proved that the data I am given is inconsistent. The first error was considering the merged cells, apparently in some docs the needed cells were not merged at all. Had to fix it manually. Another problem is that ABC columns are used by flat numbers, whereas column D is blank. So I had to change the step. Then another problem appeared is that in only two columns I and J are merged and here I stuck.. don't know how to change it.. Then columns K and L are blank and then M and N are merged again...

Comment: If 15 sheets for the first workbook is typical, you have some 300 sheets.  Don't try fixing them manually.  We need to determine all the variations and handle them automatically.  I do not think that will be too difficult because the human creators would have wanted all the sheets to look similar.